# Failed to load ldlinux.32

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, 18.04

I wanted to install Linux on my Windows10 and I used **UltraISO** to burn **ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64** to the bootable USB(FAT32, 32GB). But every time I entered the boot menu either the USB option disappears so I need to go to the AppMenu to reset everything again or it says "Failed to load ldlinux.c32".

I did browse question posted online but I couldn't find a really suitable solution. Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

[This is my laptop's system information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ps9o.png)

[This is the change I made to BOOT option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn7Tb.jpg)

[Evrytime restart the USB option disappears so I need to reset it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fCvl.jpg)

[Failed to load after proper setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NYE1.jpg)

Comment: did you try another thumbdrive?

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann just did but still won't work...just bought this one yesterday so I assumed it's not the reason. Also, I just used UNetbootin and after pressing Enter to boot the USB the screen just turns to black while an underscore keeps flashing. Does this mean the installation not correct?

Comment: This can mean many things: broken USB port, corrupt iso image, some other hardware defect, driver incompatibility,...

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann ok thanks gonna take a look at these problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! Turns out it's the UltraISO's problem. It all turned out after I switched to the Win32 Disk Imager.

(But still, don't know why this is the issue because I saw some comments that if you get "Failed to load" then it's basically UltraISO's fault. Love to know some explanations.)